# Why is 1_2_3_4 a valid integer literal in java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, integer, literals

Why does the following work?

```
int a=1_2_3_4;
System.out.println(a);   // 1234
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numeric literals are specified in [JLS 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).

> A decimal numeral is either the single ASCII digit 0, representing the integer zero, or consists of an ASCII digit from 1 to 9 optionally followed by one or more ASCII digits from 0 to 9 interspersed with underscores, representing a positive integer.

[...]

> A hexadecimal numeral consists of the leading ASCII characters 0x or 0X followed by one or more ASCII hexadecimal digits interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

[...]

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

[...]

> A binary numeral consists of the leading ASCII characters 0b or 0B followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 or 1 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

If you're asking why the underscores don't have to be in groups of three digits for decimal literals, different cultures group numbers differently - and certainly for hex and binary literals, depending on the usage, you could want all kinds of different obvious groupings.

Comment: But what is the rationale behind making such literals valid?. Isn't it better to let such literals with underscores not compile?

Comment: One benefit is to make long numbers more readable by using underscore to indicate grouping; or to indicate structure.

Comment: @paidedly: it can aid readability - particularly of large numbers, similar to the way that numbers in print often have their digits grouped in 3's or 4's with a comma or period (both depending on your culture).  C++14 has added a similar feature, using a single quote character instead of an underscore to be able to group/separate digits within a numeric literal.